# Error message when excuting sudo apt-get update

Tags: command-line, apt

Whenever I execute sudo apt-get update I get this error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jolicloud-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've checked my /etc/apt/sources.list file, but there is no reference to http://ppa.launchpad.net/jolicloud-team . Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try `grep -r jolicloud /etc/apt`

Comment: try this question: [How can I fix a 404 Error when updating packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Comment: Natty (11.04) is way beyond end of life and I would highly encourage you to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: That PPA is installed for Natty. Is that the version you're running? What's the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute

> grep -r jolicloud /etc/apt/sources.list.d

and then remove the files that are listed with this command.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a file `/etc/apt/sources.d/` with an entry for that PPA. That said, that PPA does not support Natty, and you really shouldn't be on Natty. Natty, or Ubuntu 11.04, reached End-of-Life in October 2012. Do upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases

Comment: @Hannu what am I supposed to see?

Comment: @Hannu - ubuntu releases are here - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases . IMHO, whenever possible, official pages are more palatable then wikipedia ;)

Comment: "natty" - cryptic for a newbie, I had no idea there was a natty-release, could just as well have been a special type of napkin.

Comment: https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#q=natty&safe=off -> wikipedia among first hits for me. ;-p

Comment: @Hannu Ah. OK, I'll edit.